# Rails showing strange #<Game:0xb6783820> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple page that displays some 'Games'.

Heres the code:

```
<ul>
    <%= @tvshow.games.each do |game| %>
    <li><%= game.gameTitle %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

It displays like this:

```
The All-Syrup Squishee
#<Game:0xb6783820>
```

With the #Game tag coming AFTER the list item but before the closing list tag. Any idea why it's showing up or how I could get rid of it?

Comment: You might also want to change `gameTitle` to `game_title`, as camelCase variable and method names are discouraged in Ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%=` outputs the result as markup, in this case an instance of the Game class.

For this kind of loop you want to use `<%` which executes some code but does not produce markup.

Edit line 2 to read `<% @tvshow.games.each do |game| %>`

Comment: Thanks Stef. Oversight on my part - thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Remove your first `=` from the line with the `each`

Rails is printing the result of the `each` statement, which returns the array itself. When you output an array, you will output the `.to_s` of each of its contents, which in your case is the default representations of the `Game` objects